# What would be a good approach to find similar rows between datasets?

Tags: r, dataset, similarities

I have 4 different datasets with information about people. Examples of features in these datasets are region of residence, job, education, and age. These datasets represent annual catchments over 4 years from 2014 to 2017. Members of these datasets are not identified, and there is cross-catchment with some but not all of the same members being represented in more than one dataset. About 25% of the sample is measured *de novo* from year to year. The other 75% that is surveyed from one year to the other.

The task is to identify who might be in one year and the other based on their characteristics, taking into account that there could be minor changes between the years but in general, with some level of confidence, find those who might belong to two years in a row.

I am working on R and my data consist of 500+ variables. I researched and there is a technique called [quasi-identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-identifier) that allows doing this with anonymized data, but I was looking for a more general approach to find those similar users.

Comment: It sounds like the right way to do this is not a statistical method at all. Two records either *are* from the same person or they *are not*. Since you have no validation data, or prior, you can't ascribe a probability to this event at all. What you can do is provide a deterministic profile-linkage to say, "Based on these traits, these identifiers *could be* typical of the same person measured in years 2014, 2015." I can't honestly imagine what kind of practical use your sponsor/supervisor has for such a linkage, but it's the only way to answer the question.

Comment: When you say that "member of these datasets are not identified", do you mean only from year to year, or from 1 dataset w/i a given year (employment) to another dataset (education) w/i the same year, or both? How many observations are there? Is literally no one identified? How much missing data do you have?

Comment: @gung There is no one identified at the moment, and I would like to find a general way to get an approximation on similarity based on a number of variables. Say you have occupation x1, live in x2, and has x3 degree. So based on these three variables find your possible record in the next year.

Comment: So you do know which row in the occupation table goes with which row in the address table & which row in the degree table, is that right? At some point, you're going to want to assess if the results of your method are worthwhile, is there any possibility of identifying who is who?